# Lost records in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an application which is using MySql database. 
In the last period, I am noticing that some records just disappear from the table.

The table has over 30,000 rows. It is real pain to find what is missing.

Is there any way to lock these rows so they couldn't be deleted? This morning I've found missing rows from (35748 - 35754), the previous month the same happen and I am afraid it will repeat.

I am using **MyISAM** storage engine, should I switch to InnoDB. The table is used very often for inserting and reading data as well as row updates. I switched one time to InnoDB, but then the app was very slow so I had to return to MySql. That happened a year ago.

[image: table settings]

Is there a query that I can make to show me what records are missing for all Id in the table. ID is an auto-increment.

Any suggestions on how to make this not happen again?

Comment: Are you sure these rows ever have existed? Perhaps the id takes big auto_increment leaps once in a while? (Google mysql auto_increment gaps.)

Comment: Gaps in your auto-incremented key usually doesn't  mean records have been deleted - more likely, something went wrong while creating the records and they never made it into your database.

Comment: Unless you have a very specific requirement to use MyISAM, then yes, switch to InnoDB.

Comment: @Strawberry When I switch to InnoDB, it makes my app slower. I don't know why? Any ideas

Comment: Well it's a balance between data integrity and performance. If it's a significant hit, then you have to decide about that, although the astute use of indexes is usually the biggest factor in performance. Also, as others have pointed out, in MyISAM, missing ids doesn't necessarily mean missing data.

Comment: @Marko . . . Records don't just disappear from databases.  Either they were not really create (say, the transaction was not committed) or someone deleted them.